# Using json_normalize for structured multi level dictionaries with lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've successfully transferred the data from a JSON file (structured as per the below example), into a three column `['tag', 'time', 'score']` DataFrame  using the following iterative approach:

```
for k, v in enumerate(my_request['content']):
    for k1, v1 in enumerate(v['data']['score']):
        df.loc[len(df)] = [v['tag_id'], v1['time'], v1['value']]
```

However, while this ultimately achieves the desired result, it takes a huge amount of time to iterate through larger files with the same structure. I'm assuming that an iterative approach is not the ideal way to tackle this sort of problem. Using `pandas.io.json.json_normalize` instead, I've tried the following:

```
result = json_normalize(my_request, ['content'], ['data', 'score', ['time', 'value']])
```

Which returns `KeyError: ("Try running with errors='ignore' as key %s is not always present", KeyError('data',))`. I believe I've misinterpreted the pandas documentation on `json_normalize`, and can't quite figure out how I should pass the parameters.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

*(alternatively using* `errors='ignore'` *returns* `ValueError: Conflicting metadata name data, need distinguishing prefix`*.)*

**JSON Structure**

```
 {  
   'content':[  
      {  
         'data':{  
            'score':[  
               {  
                  'time':'2015-03-01 00:00:30',
                  'value':75.0
               },
               {  
                  'time':'2015-03-01 23:50:30',
                  'value':58.0
               }
            ]
         },
         'tag_id':320676
      },
      {  
         'data':{  
            'score':[  
               {  
                  'time':'2015-03-01 00:00:25',
                  'value':78.0
               },
               {  
                  'time':'2015-03-01 00:05:25',
                  'value':57.0
               }
            ]
         },
         'tag_id':320677
      }
   ],
   'meta':None,
   'requested':'2018-04-15 13:00:00'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, while this ultimately achieves the desired result, it takes a huge amount of time to iterate through larger files with the same structure.

I would suggest the following:

1. Check whether the problem is with your iterated appends. Pandas is not very good at sequentially adding rows. How about this code:

   ```
   tups = []
   for k, v in enumerate(my_request['content']):
       for k1, v1 in enumerate(v['data']['score']):
           tups.append(v['tag_id'], v1['time'], v1['value'])
   df = pd.DataFrame(tups, columns=['tag_id', 'time', 'value])
   ```
2. If the preceding is not fast enough, check if it's the JSON-parsing part with

   ```
   for k, v in enumerate(my_request['content']):
       for k1, v1 in enumerate(v['data']['score']):
           v['tag_id'], v1['time'], v1['value']
   ```

   It is probable that 1. will be fast enough. If not, however, check if [`ujson`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson) might be faster for this case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll give these a try now. In the meantime out of curiosity, are you suggesting that `json_normalize` is not an appropriate approach to this problem?

Comment: Solution 1 worked perfectly, went from taking a few days to run, to a few seconds. Good to know I should be sequentially adding rows to a tuple instead of doing it directly in a dataframe.